# Download Environmental Geodata for Germany (SHP, KML, WMS, WFS, etc.)

Tags: germany, environment

I'm having trouble finding environmental QGIS layers for Germany. I managed to find the main ones for all the country, such as Biosphere Reserves, National Parks, Natura 2k sites, etc., but I can't find more specific information like Flood Zones, rivers / streams, forests, peatlands, renewable energy projects, etc.

Where can I find this info in downloadable format (.shp, KML, WMS, WFS, etc.), either for Germany in general or for it's Federal States (e.g. Bayern)?

Answer (score 0):

This can be quite cumbersome since there are many insitutions reponsible for data collection / publication, on a national or state level.

Let's see if we can the data you're looking for, even if it has been a while since you asked:

- Flood zones for Bavaria as WMS is available at [LfU Bayern](https://www.lfu.bayern.de/umweltdaten/geodatendienste/index_detail.htm?id=4cab2c12-fa7e-49c3-97ba-f4f33af3a598&profil=WMS) (see "Bezug" tab).
- Streams, forests and peatlands can be extracted from ATKIS Basis-DLM which you can download from [LDBV Bayern](https://geodaten.bayern.de/opengeodata/OpenDataDetail.html?pn=atkis_basis_dlm) in various formats (NAS/SHP/GeoPackage/WFS). Pretty strange that LfU Bayern does not provide a simple stream network for download, if you ask me.
- Forests and peatlands can also be extracted from the Corine Land Cover dataset. CLC5-2018 is available at [BKG](https://gdz.bkg.bund.de/index.php/default/open-data/corine-land-cover-5-ha-stand-2018-clc5-2018.html) and CLC25-2018 at [UBA](https://www.umweltbundesamt.de/themen/boden-flaeche/flaechensparen-boeden-landschaften-erhalten/corine-land-cover-clc) (both SHP).

Moreover, you might be interested in the following sites to scan for additional data:

- [Geoportal BfG](https://geoportal.bafg.de/CSWView/od.xhtml)
- [Umweltatlas Bayern](https://www.umweltatlas.bayern.de/mapapps/resources/apps/umweltatlas/index.html?lang=de), layers for download available.
- [Geodatendienste LfU Bayern](https://www.lfu.bayern.de/umweltdaten/geodatendienste/index.htm), supplied via WMS and available for download.